# PHP - Uploaded file is null

Tags: php, file, upload, null

When I try to upload a file in PHP, It will not let me. After dumping variables here and there, I got this:

```
Invalid file!
!
NULL
24M
32MNULL
```

Which came from this:

```
echo "Invalid file!"; //So, we screwed up...
echo "<br />" . $ext . "!<br />";
echo var_dump($_FILES['fileupl']);
echo "<br />" . ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
echo "<br />" . ini_get('post_max_size');
echo "<br />" . var_dump($_FILES['error']);
```

Any file I upload will return that.
I'm trying to upload any file that is: .zip, .jar, .png for a little minecraft file sharing platform.

Variables:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];

    $type = $_GET['type'];

    //File stuff
    $name = $_FILES['fileupl']['name'];
    $rname = $_FILES['fileupl']['tmp_name'];
    $ftype = $_FILES['fileupl']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['fileupl']['size'];
    $ext = strrchr($rname, '.');
    $allowedExtensions = array(".zip", ".jar", ".png");
```

Code:

```
if (!in_array(end(explode(".",
            strtolower($name))),
            $allowedExtensions)) { 

            echo "Invalid file!"; //dafuq, how'd you screw that up man?
            echo "<br />" . $ext . "!<br />";
            echo var_dump($_FILES['fileupl']);
            echo "<br />" . ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
            echo "<br />" . ini_get('post_max_size');
            echo "<br />" . var_dump($_FILES['error']);
        }
        else
        {
            $uploaddir = './content/';

            //Begin file shizzle

            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupl']['tmp_name'])) //Is the file uploaded?
            {
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($name);
                echo $name . " Uploaded successfully.";
                if (move_uploaded_file($rname, $uploadfile))
                {
                    echo $name . " (" . display_filesize($size) . ") Successfully uploaded!";
                    $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `content`(`type`, `creator`, `title`, `description`, `filename`) VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($type) . "', '" . $username . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($title) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($desc) . "', 'Anon')");
                    if (!$q)
                    {
                        echo "mySQL execution failed!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Uploaded to database!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "File could not be moved!";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                echo "File could not be uploaded!";
                echo var_dump($_FILES['fileupl']);
                echo "<br />" . ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
                echo "<br />" . ini_get('post_max_size');
            }
        }
```

I've tried just about everything and would greatly appreciate it if someone knew what was happening.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you print_r($_FILES) ?

Comment: Is the `enctype` in your form `multipart/data`?

Comment: What's the encoding type on the form that is posting the data?

Comment: Matt; I added that, no difference. and print_r($_FILES) gives me "Array ( ) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned after fixing the form, you're now seeing: (I've edited for clarity)

```
Invalid file! 
!    
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "EasyMinecraft.zip" ["type"]=> string(15) "application/zip" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php87jMDe" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(4325565) } 
24M 
32MNULL 
Array ( [fileupl] => Array ( [name] => EasyMinecraft.zip [type] => application/zip [tmp_name] => /tmp/php87jMDe [error] => 0 [size] => 4325565 ) )
```

This shows that $ext is empty.  The relevant lines of the variable assignment are:

```
$rname = $_FILES['fileupl']['tmp_name'];
$ext = strrchr($rname, '.');
```

So, what's `$_FILES['fileupl']['tmp_name']`?  Your output shows it to be */tmp/php87jMDe*, which is clearly not going to work when you attempt to find everything after a '.' in it, as there is no period in it.  You probably want to change that first line to use the actual name, as opposed to the tmp_name, e.g.:

```
$rname = $_FILES['fileupl']['name'];
```

You're also going to have an error with this conditional:

```
if (!in_array(end(explode(".",
            strtolower($name))),
            $allowedExtensions)) {
```

Note that `end(explode(".", strtolower($name)))` is going to give you just 'zip', not '.zip'.  I'm not sure why you're trying to redected the extension here, rather than using the `$ext` you already created? I'd suggest lower-casing `$ext` when you create it, and I think you should be good to go then?

Comment: The reason it was tmp_name is because when I tried before all of this I thought it would be the tmp_name, since it would still have the extension. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: @AdamM Would you mind accepting an answer?  Either mine or Raidenance's - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add multpart formdata to the  tag and try

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: now getting: Invalid file!
!
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "EasyMinecraft.zip" ["type"]=> string(15) "application/zip" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php87jMDe" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(4325565) }
24M
32MNULL
Array ( [fileupl] => Array ( [name] => EasyMinecraft.zip [type] => application/zip [tmp_name] => /tmp/php87jMDe [error] => 0 [size] => 4325565 ) )